# What happens with pointers in C if given a Value instead of address?

Tags: c, pointers

So my code snippet is this

```
char* ptr = "Hello";
```

Here `ptr` points to what? I think it points to "H".

Why doesn't this pointer `ptr` behave like a normal pointer?

Because when I wrote `printf("%s" ,*ptr)`, it didn't give me the value but instead raised an error. Yet when I wrote `printf("%s" , ptr)` it gave me "Hello"  as output.

Why does this behavior happen?

What is actually stored in pointer `ptr` ?

Comment: Yes, it points to `H`. `*ptr` thus gives you `H`, however `%s` expects the pointer not a character so it can continue printing the other letters in your string. `%c` would have worked with `*ptr`.

Comment: Because `*ptr` is a `char` and not a string.

Comment: I think you real misunderstanding is what `%s` means and how strings are handled i C. Anyway `ptr` behaves just like all other pointers,

Comment: FYI, pointers are variables that have values, like other variables.  Pointers have a pointer type and that enable certain operations on them, while disallowing others.  But the value held in a pointer variable is a memory address, which is just a number, an unsigned integer in machine code.

Comment: What does this have to do with the tags [assembly][x86]?  You haven't mentioned anything that's specific to asm on a particular machine; this is fully explainable in terms of the C abstract machine.  (Except for why the UB results in a segfault instead of some other weirdness.)  If you want to know the asm details, single step the asm in a debugger such as GDB.  (e.g. use `layout reg`, and look at the memory holding the `ptr` variable, and look at how the asm differs for your working vs. broken source code versions.  Should make it obvious if you know asm but are only just learning C?)

Answer (score 2):

Your core misunderstanding here may be that you think that a "string" is a thing that you can pass around and do things with in your program, just like you can with an int or a float or a structure.  When you tried to write

```
printf("%s", *ptr);
```

perhaps you thought that `ptr` was a pointer, but you didn't want to print the pointer, you wanted to print the whole string pointed to by the pointer, so you put that `*` in there to "take the contents of the pointer".

The flaw in your reasoning is that there is no such thing, in C, as a string that you might be able to, say, pass as a whole to `printf` for it to print.

C does have strings, of course, but they're implemented as arrays.  And arrays are second-class citizens in C: you can most definitely *not* pass them around and do things with them the way you can with ints, floats, and structs.

Whenever you try to do something with an array, what you get (whether you wanted it or not, whether you realized it or not) is a pointer to the array's first element.

So even though we say that the `%s` format in `printf` is for printing "a string", what `printf` does *not* expect is that you will pass the entire string to it — because printf knows you will have no way of doing that.  So, instead, the `%s` format in `printf` expects to receive *a pointer to the first character in the string*.

Answer (score 1):

> So my code snippet is this
>
> ```
> char* ptr = "Hello";
> ```
>
> Here `ptr` points to what? I think it points to "H".

`ptr` points to the first character of a six-element array of `char` containing the characters 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'.  The specific `char` stored in the location to which `ptr` points is 'H'.  Note well that that is different from the *string* `"H"`.

> Why doesn't this pointer `ptr` behave like a normal pointer?

It behaves exactly like any other `char` pointer, with one caveat (which you have not exercised): because it points to a character inside a string literal, you must not attempt to use it to modify that character or others in the literal.

> Because when I wrote `printf("%s" ,*ptr)`, it didn't gave me the value
> but instead instead raised an error.

Well yes, that's reasonable, although you cannot *rely* on an error here.  When you write bogus code like that, you may just get weird behavior.  Or even normal-seeming behavior.

If you want to print the one `char` to which `ptr` directly points, then the correct formatting directive is `%c`:

```
printf("%c" ,*ptr);  /* *ptr is a char, not a pointer to one */
```

> Yet when I wrote `printf("%s" , ptr)` it gave me "Hello" as output.

The `%s` directive, on the other hand, expects its argument to be a pointer to the first character of a string (as `ptr` indeed is), and the whole pointed-to string is printed.

> Why does this behavior happen?

Because that's what's supposed to happen.  It's unclear why you expected something else.

> What is actually stored in pointer ptr ?

The address of the first character of the string literal `"Hello"`.

Answer (score 0):

`char *ptr = "Hello";`

`ptr` points to `H`

`H` is a char.

So you need to have - `printf("%c", *ptr);` to print just the char.
This is the same as `printf("%c", ptr[0]);`

Obviously `%s` is an array of chars, so `%s` will print the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with what the `char*` points at. The `%s` specifier of `printf` family of functions is simply defined to expect a nul-terminated character array as parameter.

`printf("%s" ,*ptr)` is an undefined behavior and anything can happen.

> What is actually stored in pointer ptr ?

The address of the string literal/character array `"Hello"`, located in read-only memory. Or the first item of that array if you will, same address.